# Adobe AIR Corrupt file

Tags: windows, chkdsk, adobe-air

I got this software that requires adobe AIR, I've installed it and I keep getting this corrupt file message:

```
AdobeAIRInstaller.exe - Corrupt File
The file or directory C:\$Mft is corrupt and unreadable.
Please run the Chkdsk utility
```

Not sure what to do and where to find this utility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `C:\$Mft` entity is not a real file, it is an internal NTFS structure called Master File Table which stores information about physical position of all of your files on that volume (it is just a coincidence that the error is displayed by an Adobe software). You can check a volume (and fix any errors encountered) by opening the command shell (Start > Run... or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut), typing in `chkdsk c: /f /r` and rebooting (as described in [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315265)).

Also I must note that if you have encountered an error like this you hard drive is probably failed or is about to fail, so **backup all important data**! Even if it is a software fault, it can corrupt your data as well.

Comment: `$MFT` *is* a real file. It has a file entry like every other file too. Just look on your hard drive. The same goes for the other »meta«-files in NTFS as well.

Comment: It is not a file in the sense that it is used by internals of filesystem itself, and changing it would affect not only it's contents. Of course, formally you are absolutely right.